# Same result different case in Swift?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'd like in a switch statement the same thing to be done for different cases, e.g.

```
let a = 2
switch a {
case 2:
    print( "hi" )
case 3:
    print( "hi" )
default:
    print( "monkey" )
}
```

I've tried this syntax, but it errors:

```
case 2 || 3: ...
```

Is there a syntactical way to do this rather than to put what's in the duplicate cases into a refactored function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a comma – `case 2, 3:`. I would highly recommend reading the Swift language guide [section on switch statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID127) (you'll have to scroll down a tad).

Comment: @Hamish: you're my hero!

Comment: ... and it is described (with examples)  in the Swift book in the section about the switch statement.

Comment: Or using a closed range `case 2...3`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/207/switch/777/matching-multiple-values#t=201608272055086333221

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the quick responses--the answer was to insert a comma or to use a closed range such as:

```
let a = 2
switch a {
case 2, 3:
    print( "hi" )
default:
    print( "monkey" )
}
```

or

```
let a = 2
switch a {
case 2...3:
    print( "hi" )
default:
    print( "monkey" )
}
```